# How to get the dom element in js file when html document is rendered by jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The content of HTML body is defined in **a.html** file instead of **index.html**. Then this content is loaded to **index.html** via jquery *load()* function. How can I get the **".test-img"** class element in **a.js** file?

This is the **index.html** file:

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>

  <div id="myContent"></div>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#myContent").load("a.html"); 
    });
  </script> 

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the **a.html** file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">   
    <div class="title">test</div>
    <img class="test-img" src="test.jpg" >
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the **main.js** file:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/a.js"></script>');
```

Comment: Aside from the use of `document.write`, which should be avoided, why does `main.js` just contain a line to add `a.js` to the DOM? That's seems entirely redundant. To answer the question, you can just retrieve the element from the DOM in any usual way, `querySelector()` or jQuery

Comment: On https://api.jquery.com/load/ it says that `.load` supports a `complete` callback. You can be sure that the contents of `a.html` are loaded inside `#myContent` at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, marcus!

The first thing will be to make sure that your `load` function has executed before the contents of `a.js` is excecuted. So if your `index.html` delays the loading of `a.html` until after pageload (as it looks now), then make sure `a.js`, which tries to get `.test-img`, also happens after pageload. If that is the case, everything should be fine! `a.js` will be executed from within your `index.html`, which will have your `a.html` inside its DOM.

Note that you could consider using `jQuery.getScript()` to execute `a.js` right after you have loaded `a.html`. Then `a.js` itself doesn't need to worry about delaying execution.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, I use the `jQuery.getScript('a.js')` in the callback of `.load("a.html", callback)`, it works.